# On Thunderbird 12, how can I see attached images expanded on message body?

Tags: windows-7, thunderbird

I just wanna to open e-mail messages on my Thunderbird and see attached images without the need for manually opening attachments, like a lot of webmails, that show at least their thumbnails...

Comment: Probably unrelated:  Why are still you on Thunderbird 12?  Thunderbird 14 is out now.

Comment: I use LiberKey, a portable app manager. I had some troubles with automatic updates, so I update manually after some months :) Well, Tb 12 do the work well and it is not the cause of that issue (not seeing attached images on message body), so why to use the last version?

Comment: Upgraded to 13. 14 is not on LK yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View > Display Attachments Inline.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Welcome to Super User! I suggest you [add more detail](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5177/what-do-we-do-with-low-quality-answers-from-high-rep-users) to this question so that it can be more useful to future users.

Comment: So easy :) I did not see that option... It was an objective answer - liked it.

Answer (score 1):

Thunderbird already does this in default configuration. If it does not work for you, make sure that the image is really attached to the mail and not just linked in a HTML mail. Automatically fetching (and displaying) linked images would be a privacy threat, as one could see if and when you read a mail by looking at the server's log file. You can set exceptions based on sender addresses however.

Note: Thunderbird 12 is outdated and contains [known security vulnerabilities](http://www.mozilla.org/security/known-vulnerabilities/thunderbird.html). Update to current version.

Comment: Well, it wasn't my TB default config... Nice to know which threats are corrected from TB12 to TB14. I'm now thinking about doing that update...